# Can I use fontawesome icons without the bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have downloaded the fontawesome icons into a folder and the CSS into another folder. I would like to try them out now but I am currently getting:

```
"Error 503 Backend is unhealthy, Backend is unhealthy,Guru Meditation: XID: 1379938886 Varnish cache server"
```

when I go to the Example page on the fontawesome web site.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Can someone give me a very very simple example of how I can use an SVG font icon inside a DIV. Just the simplest would be good as I can then work out how to modify it.

Also I just want the very minimum so can I use the SVG without adding bootstrap.css files?

Comment: That's an HTTP error; your server is down.  What server is it?

Comment: Not my server :-(  It's the github web page.

Comment: The error you're getting is from the font awesome site.  Go to http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ and you'll see the error.

Comment: The font awesome site has an example on how to use it without Bootstrap.  Now, if the site were up, we could point you to it.  I use it in a PHP site that does not have Bootstrap.  Basically, you just include the CSS and JS files...not much more to it than that.

Comment: I realize it's the fontawesome web site but I am hoping someone can give me an example of how I could use the SVG.  I don't have any code right now. Just looking for a starter example and can I use it without bootstrap css file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At http://fontawesome.io/get-started/  there's a "Not using Bootstrap?" section how to use it without Bootstrap.

And here: http://fontawesome.io/examples/  are examples how to use it.
e.g. in a div:

```
<div><i class="icon-camera-retro"></i></div>
```

Comment: Note that the non-bootstrap section of the documentation is no longer provided with FA 4. Legacy instructions are now at http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/get-started/.

Answer (score 0):

The most current way to use Font Awesome without Bootstrap is to add their "kit code".

Log in or create an account at - http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ to get your kit code. Once you get it - just add it to the `<head>` section. The kit code looks like this ->

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/**********.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```